# Application.Open URL

Tags: unity, c#, ios

I am developing a simple application on Unity, on a Mac. I am trying to open an URL with the simple command Application.OpenURL on visual studio when it doesn't work : When I start to write application on visual studio it doesn't show the commands available. Do I miss something?[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to execute it right away, you might want to place it in Start(). This is not valid Unity syntax what you have.

Comment: This is not even valid C#. The reason why the syntax completion doesn't show you `Application` is because you can't have a method call at that position. I recommend taking a very basic C# programming course and learn the fundamentals of the language and how to use it in Unity.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I followed all tutorials for this simple task and they all they the same. Like this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w203KP1oqfI

Comment: My bad, sorry about that, checked again and I found my error.

Comment: For future reference, the norm here is to post code & errors, whenever possible, as formatted text (rather than images & screenshots). It's a lot easier for the community to look stuff up, run & debug the code, etc when we can copy & paste the information in question. Some problems are trivial enough to get noticed at a glance. But if the problem is more complex requiring others to rekey everything adds friction to the process which often reduces the likelihood of getting answers.

Answer (score 2):

The method call must be in an active method for it to be called. Try something like this if you want it to be called at the initiation of the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenURL : MonoBehavior
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Application.OpenURL("https://www.romainlalire.com");
    }
}
```